# Assign 0 or 1 with different probabilities conditional on another column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to assign a 0 or 1 with some stochasticity based on another column in a data frame (`outcome`). If `outcome == 1`, the new column `exposure` should equal 1 about 90% of the time. Conversely if `outcome == 0` it should equal 1 about 20% of the time.

I am currently doing this with a `for` loop but wondering if there are more efficient/elegant ways to accomplish this (i.e. via vectorization).

To be clear, though the data frame is labeled `example_data` this is **not** an example - its the test data I am generating to test a series of functions related to GEE models.

```
set.seed(05062020)
example_data <- data.frame(id = as.factor(rep(sprintf("Record %s",seq(1:50)), each = 2)),
                           outcome = as.factor(rep(sample(0:1, 50, prob = c(0.8,0.2), replace = TRUE), each = 2)))

for (i in 1:nrow(example_data)){
  example_data$exposure[i] <- ifelse(example_data$outcome[i] == 1, 
                                sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(0.1, 0.9)),
                                sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
example_data$exposure <- ifelse(example_data$outcome == 1, 
                                sample(0:1, nrow(example_data), prob = c(0.1, 0.9), replace = T),
                                sample(0:1, nrow(example_data), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), replace = T))
```

`ifelse` is vectorized, so we can do this with one function call.

Comment: Ack I tried this but forgot to add the `replace = TRUE` and so it didnt work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sampling coin flips with data-dependent probabilities can often be done elegantly by thresholding a uniform random variable:

```
example_data$exposure <-
  as.numeric(runif(nrow(example_data)) <= 0.2 + 0.7*(example_data$outcome==1))
```

So basically the threshold is 0.2 when `example_data$outcome == 0` and is 0.9 when `example_data$outcome == 1`. I used `0.7*(example_data$outcome==1)` instead of just `0.7*example_data$outcome` because `example_data$outcome` is defined as a factor in your data frame, and the `as.numeric` converts `TRUE/FALSE` into `1/0`.